# How to download Visual Studio 2013 update 2 offline/standalone installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, download, offline

As downloadable [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42666) but to be an online installtion process.

I'm looking to ways to download the package offline and/or the standalone .iso installation file - similarly to how we can do with Visual Studio 2012 updates [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305).

How can I do that?

ps.

A [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=download%20visual%20studio%202013%20update%20offline%20standalone&start=10) give me nowhere helpful at this time.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2015, the guide is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30077959/248616

Answer (score 25):

In brief the answer is [this download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393220).

As I have met this question many times for Visual Studio versions, I note down here the full process to access them all from A to Z.

1. Google search for `visual studio updates` as [here](https://www.google.com.vn/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=visual%20studio%20updates&spell=1)
2. Go for links from `visualstudio.com` as [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/)
3. Search for `updates` on the page - pick up the search result [Overview of Visual Studio 2013 updates‎](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2829760) which lists all latest Visual Studio updates.
4. Choose the version to open the download page.
5. Look for `Installation Instruction` section, SCROLL DOWN below to the part that says `Download the ISO image directly`
6. Enjoy your .iso - it's done here.

---

**Google search**

[image]

---

**Go down for .iso downloading**

[image]

Comment: Looks like the "Install Instructions" section with the iso link has gone from that page  :-(

Comment: This is the link for the curent update (VS2013 Update 5) https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=519391

Comment: From step 3 cannot arrive "pick up the search result Overview of Visual Studio 2013 updates‎ which lists all latest Visual Studio updates" now....

Comment: 1, go here https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/
2, Join Visual Studio Dev Essentials for free
3, you will be redirected to: https://my.visualstudio.com/
4, enter into downloads section and search: visual studio community 2013
5, you will find the download content. just choose DVD as the media

Comment: It's not apparent which version users are being directed to above, but beware:

"In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above."

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: Adding to what @efinal said, if you click on "Visual Studio" from the "featured" tab, all you get is Visual Studio 2017 (!), you have to click on downloads and search for it to find anything older than that.

Answer (score 18):

I found one way to do this via [this article](http://www.techtronic.us/blog/post/technology/visual-studio-2012-update-2-offline-installer/) by storing the downloaded files. Though not a way to have iso file though.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, this also works for VS2013 at least up to update 3 (which is the newest one at the time of writing)

Comment: Thanks for referencing my blog!  This works for all versions, all updates.

Answer (score 7):

VS 2013 Update 2 offline ISO - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393220

VS 2013 Update 3 offline ISO - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=403041

Answer (score 4):

For more current releases/updates (e.g. MSVC 2013 update 4 etc.) Microsoft [recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/e2h7fzkw.aspx#bkmk_offline) adding the '/layout' option when running the online installer from the command prompt:

```
<executable name> /layout
```

This command downloads **all** the packages for the installation, which makes it possible to install them offline thereafter.

Answer (score 3):

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=519391

that's it ! the update 5 direct Link .. it's 6GB ISO

Answer (score 2):

I got this link for update 3 from [Xinystudio](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/visual-studio-2013-update3-offline-iso/):

[Visual Studio 2013 update 3 offline iso](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842997)

I know the OP is asking for update 2 but I thought this may present a better alternative.

Comment: Something officially from microaoft site can be trusted. Xinyatudio is the first time to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a number of people in your team that will need the udpate, it is a good idea to get someone to download the file to a local share and then share the location with yours team, as this file takes quite a while to download normally, and you are not able to use Visual Studio while the download has started.

One other way to do this is to go to the "**Overview of Visual Studio 2013 updates**" page (link below) and download the latest VS update.

"**Overview of Visual Studio 2013 updates**" - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829760.

On this page click on "**Download the latest Visual Studio 2013 update package now**" and you will be redirected to the VS update page, where you will be able to download the file.

**VS 2013 Update 5 direct link**:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48129

So if you have downloaded the file to **C:\downloads**, go to the command prompt and navigate to C:\downloads (or ***shift + right-click*** on the folder, then selecting "**open command window here**" .

Once you are in this folder, type the following command:

**VS2013.5.exe /layout**

[image]

This should bring up the Visual Studio Update window, and the download will then start.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) do the following:

[image: How to download Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 offline installer]