# Typescript 1.5 for VS2015 without internet access

Tags: visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

is it possible to install typescript 1.5 on visual studio 2015 without an internet access? As it comes "out of the box" with VS2015 it seems that no installer exists (except for the 1.5 beta)

But if you have no internet access, the VS installation ends with a warning because it cannot download the typescript tool. And at the end, the typescript tool is not present in the extensions list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TypeScript installers are available at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593.

see **Details** section, and you should find a **[Download]** link next to the TypeScript 1.5.3/TypeScript 1.5.4.

Comment: Hmmm quite hard to find as the title is typescript for vs 2012. However, it is simpler to download it from here than the first method, even if they both work. The typescript team should really provide a link on their site even if it is supposed to be included in vs 2015

Answer (score 1):

Found a way!

1. Run "vs_community.exe /layout" from cmd to download all installation files (Reference: [How to install VS2015 Community Edition offline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070585/1454888))
2. Then navigate to the folder (inside the download directory) "OfflineCache\installers".
3. You will see two TS folders: "TypeScriptV1" and "TypeScriptV2". They are the installers for the versions 1.5.3 and 1.5.4 respectively.

Comment: @sroll I searched for those installers in the entire internet. This was the only solution I found to get them. I needed the installer for TypeScripts Tools 1.5.3 to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888115/visual-studio-2015-rtm-lost-js-support-after-update-typesript-tools

Comment: tested and approved, version 1.5.3 works perfectly. I haven't try version 1.5.4 as you had problems with it.