# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition License

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

I downloaded Visual studio 2015 Community Edition and installed it using the guidance in this post [How to install VS2015 Community Edition offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070584/how-to-install-vs2015-community-edition-offline)

It installed and seemed to be fine but soon after the application said I now required a license code.  Considering this is the Community Edition installed on a home PC why is it asking for a key code?  It is definitely the Community Edition because the installed item says so.  What is wrong with my install?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably are seeing is the request to *register* your version with Microsoft, which is required within 30 days of first usage.

For this you need only some email-address of yours that can be used to create a Microsoft account. You even can register more than one installations with the same account.

You can check the status of your license via *Help/About Visual Studio*
[image: screenshot]
[image]

when you click on *check for an updated license* you are asked for your Microsoft account.

Comment: The OP used the off-line installation instructions, so it's not clear if this is an option.

Comment: @guntbert Thanks for prompt response.  I thought I had registered it through my hotmail account details.  I will check though!!