# VS2017 Community edition change registration account

Tags: visual-studio-2017, account, license-key

As per [this type of question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33585447/31326) VS2017 Community Edition has to be registered within 30 days, otherwise it will refuse to work after that time.

My 30 days are up, but the system that I am working on does not belong to me, it belongs to a client of mine.  Ideally this copy of VS2017 should be registered to an account belonging to my client, (and even more security conscious I should not know the account details)

So if I register VS2017 with my account credentials, can I later on change the VS2017 registration to my client's account?

Note that I am not changing the type of license, just the entity the software is registered to.

---

Edit: Changed wording to clarify what I am wanting to do, based on @MSalters comment

Comment: This looks like a legal question to me. A license is a legal contract, and you cannot unilaterally change the parties to a contract except as allowed by the terms of that contract. And I strongly suspect the VS2017 EULA doesn't allow you to change the EU. Does it matter? If the client is qualified, they can enter into a new contract with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legally you can't transfer *your* license, but an existing Visual Studio installation can be re-registered. See `Help>Register Product`.

Comment: I had to start up a personal computer of mine that already has VS2017 licensed to me.   Under `Help->Register Product` the only options for changing accounts are for `Sign in to Visual Studio`.  I can remove my account from that section, but it it still says the product is licensed to me.  There is no option (obvious to me) for changing who the product is licensed to.

Comment: @PeterM: Isn't there a "check license"? Apparently the Microsoft registration servers in my area are borked, so I can't check it right now.

Comment: OK. I didn't take that link to mean `change registration`.  I have up a dialog box that is asking for me to log into my Microsoft account.

Comment: I created a dummy hotmail account and changed to the license to that.  The licensing dialog box is now saying that the product is licensed to my new account.  And then I changed back to my account.  Success!