# I can't download visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried to download visual studio community 2015 but when it's getting downloaded, it kept stopping.
Then SQL server 2012 native client was told to have been failed.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: You could download the .ISO maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution is to download ISO file and install it (offline mode)
Second solution is to remove everything related to Visual Studio
Third solution is to download Visual Studio Express for specific platform (for desktop in your case)

ISO solution: [How to install VS2015 Community Edition offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070584/how-to-install-vs2015-community-edition-offline)