# References in Visual Studio 2015 cannot be recognized

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

This is very weird for me but I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 and I created a universal project for windows 10. But it seems visual studio can't recognize assembly references in the project. Just have a look at the picture below:

App.xaml.cs 
[image: App.xaml.cs]

MainPage.xaml.cs
[image: MainPage.xaml.cs]

Errors page 1
[image]

Errors page 2
[image]

I am using windows 10 and I also have visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re target your project framework or drop and re install the framework. .

Comment: That does not help. I don't understand why people think this question is unclear or doesn't show research?
I tried this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070584/how-to-install-vs2015-community-edition-offline) and tried downloading offline. But it keeps downloading. The size of the downloaded folder is about 14 gb. Can someone please tell me what is the original size? I just want to make Windows 10 apps. Visual Studio 2015 is so much difficult to use now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i have solved it after couple of weeks. I apologise for posting it late. My question was marked unclear. But its a known issue.

The problem is with the Visual Studio 2015 Community installer. When you download it from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) then after downloading installer you have start the setup. The setup does not download all the packages which are necessary for Windows 10 Universal Apps / UWP apps and its size is around 3 GBs.

As I mentioned this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070584/how-to-install-vs2015-community-edition-offline) before in a comment. According to that post download it offline using this command line `C:\vs_community.exe /layout` in your command prompt. It asks you for download location. And yes you will need internet connection for that. You have to download until it finishes. I had a terrible internet connection so what I did is I start the download offline every time the internet connection lost and select the same location where I wanted to download.

I hope it works.

Thanks.